# How to change the Ruby version in Gemfile

Tags: ruby

I tried starting Zammad from cPanel, and when I executed the command

```
bundle install --without test development mysql
```

I got an error about the version of Ruby in the `Gemfile`:

```
Your ruby version is 2.4.3 but your Gemfile specified 2.5.5
```

I manually changed the version of Ruby in the `Gemfile`, but the error persists. It seems that it does not support my modification:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# core - base
ruby '2.4.3'
gem 'rails', '5.2.3'

# core - rails additions
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'activerecord-session_store
gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
gem 'json'
gem 'rails-observers'
```

Comment: check Gemfile.lock

Comment: there is no gemfile.lock

Comment: finally, i deleted gemfile and upload it, it's work